# No tiny wysiwyg editor for Bootstrap não funciona a criação de hyperlinks no Internet Explorer

Tags: jquery, bootstrap, internet-explorer, editor-de-texto, wysiwyg

Estou utilizando o **editor wysiwyg Tiny**, porém estou tendo problemas ao tentar inserir um hyperlink em um texto digitado no editor. Isso ocorre somente no internet explorer, e da seguinte forma:

Após digitar o texto, seleciono o trecho que quero aplicar o hyperlink. Feito isso, clico na opção de hyperlink da barra de ferramentas do editor. Abre um div em uma camada acima, com um campo para digitar a url do hyperlink e um botão adicionar. Quando clico no campo para começar a digitar a url, ele simplesmente não aceita a digitação, perde o foco, que volta para a área do editor, apagando o texto que estava selecionado e substituindo-o pela url que comecei a digitar. Com isso não consigo criar um hyperlink dentro do texto.

Alguém, já passou por essa situação? Já olhei o tutorial e não consegui identificar nada falando sobre esse problema. Mesmo a demo do tutorial (https://mindmup.github.io/bootstrap-wysiwyg/), se for aberta no internet explorer, também não funciona.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]